# Why exactly does the interaction of a positron and an electron result in energy?

Tags: energy-conservation, antimatter

Forgive the extremely basic question, but I'd like to know exactly **why** the collision of these two particles results in the release of energy (EM radiation?)

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean by "why" because there are a lot of layers to that onion. What we know for sure is that matter/antimatter particle pairs both are attracted to each other electromagnetically and there is no other force or quantum principle preventing them from getting arbitrarily close to one another to the point where they essentially occupy the same space at the same time. Why THAT results in annihilation rather than, say, the formation of a black hole, I don't think can be known without a theory of quantum gravity, but I look forward to being corrected there.

Comment: What logical possibilities do you want excluded?

Comment: Maybe you should look at the algebra of four vectors http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html, in addition to conservation laws in particle interactions http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/parint.html

Comment: @CosmasZachos other possibilities to exclude: (1) they become a black hole (they obviously don't but why); (2) they become some kind of weird massive boson with zero spin and zero charge. Why does the mass become disrupted to become mostly massless?

Comment: @Peter Moore (1) requires their Compton wavelength to be less than their Schwarzschild radius, (2) All such light neutral bosons have been excluded experimentally. No mass is disrupted: mass is easy come easy go, if allowed kinematically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that mass is already a form of energy ($E=mc^2$) and so electron-positron annihilation doesn't "create" energy, it just transforms it. In general nature prefers to convert mass into other kinds of energy, just as it prefers to convert potential energy into kinetic energy. So for example a free muon will decay into an electron and some other particles:
$$
\mu^{-} \rightarrow e^{-} + \nu_{\mu} + \bar{\nu_e}
$$
Both the left and right sides of the above equation have the same conserved quantum numbers (charge, lepton number, and so on) but the sum of the rest masses on the right hand side is less than the sum on the left, and so the right hand side is preferred.

An isolated electron is stable because in:
$$
e^{-} \rightarrow X
$$
there are no combination of particles you can put in for $X$ that will both have the same quantum numbers as an electron and also lower total rest mass.

Positrons and electrons, however, have opposite quantum numbers, so a system consisting of a positron and an electron ends up having a net charge of 0 (similarly for lepton number and other conserved quantities). So in
$$
e^{-} + e^{+} \rightarrow \gamma + \gamma
$$
the left and right hand side have the same conserved numbers, but the right hand side has less rest mass... so that's the side that nature prefers. Note that you need *two* photons in order to preserve momentum.

(For the pedantic: there are some details glossed over somewhat in my answer and "nature prefers lower rest mass" is an oversimplification, but the details are probably out of scope for what the OP is looking for.)

Comment: Hey; I'd actually love to know why nature prefers lower rest mass! The elaboration would definitely help in my currently basic surface level understanding.

Comment: That's probably worth another question, but I think the short answer is that the entropy of lower rest mass particles is greater than that of higher rest mass particles: that is, there are more configurations of momentum & energy available to two photons than there are to an electron and positron, because a great deal of the energy for the massive particles is "frozen" in their rest masses. So reverse annihilation, where two photons combine to make an electron and positron, is possible but very very unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one way to look at this is uncertainty. If the positron and electron existed at the same point in space then there would be no uncertainty in their positions relative to one another By becoming an  electromagnetic radiation wave they are spread out at no particular location.
This would mean black holes cant have infinite density too.
It is also the case that gamma rays crashing into lead become positrons and electrons so reversing this means positrons and electrons become gamma rays

Answer (score -1):

The "why" is charge. Charge couples to the electromagnetic field. The reason there is (mostly$^1$) only EM radiation and no matter left is because the positron is the antimatter complement of the electron, so all their conserved quantum numbers are complementary (charge, lepton number), and add to zero.

Also, they don't have color charge, so strong interactions do not occur.

[1] The leptons interact via the weak interaction, so $e^++e^-\rightarrow Z \rightarrow \nu_e + \bar\nu_e $ is possible, but not experimentally detectable, even if the amplitude were large (it is not). See https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9602382

Comment: You haven't actually said why the annihilation releases energy. Perhaps you should say something about conservation of energy...

Comment: "electron number?" All of the uses of that phrase that I can find (90-second Google search) seem to come from chemistry. How can it be an absolute conserved quantity if, for example, a free neutron can undergo beta decay to become an electron and a proton?

Comment: @SolomonSlow try "lepton number", which isn't always conserved b/c of neutrino oscillations. In normal weak decays and interactions, each generation's number is conserved. Also: your free neutron decay is missing something...a neutral little thing.

Comment: Yeah I don't think this really explains it either. Why don't all oppositely charged particles annihilate? And why don't antimatter and matter pairs become black holes when they meet? And why does the mass become energy? Does the Higgs Field get disrupted somehow? My point is I don't think the OPs question is really capable of being answered the way it's asked without quantum gravity.

Comment: @PeterMoore because quantum numbers are conserved, and only matter/anti-matter pairs have complimentary quantum numbers that add to 0. Since photons are their own antiparticles, you can make them one at a time. Moreover, the final state of $e^+e^-$ is not "energy", it's 2 or more photons...weak interaction notwithstanding.

Comment: Mass is converted to energy, and no one has answered (or can answer) "why". If we could then we could harness E = mc2 to power all of civilization. It's really staggering what we don't have the slightest clue about but it doesn't stop people from pretending otherwise.

Comment: @Peter Mass is a form of energy, like Euros are a form of money. You can convert mass to other forms of energy (eg kinetic energy), like you can convert Euros to US dollars.

Comment: @PeterMoore Mass is just energy at zero momentum, it's the minimum energy required to create one excitation in the particle's quantum field. In de Broglie terms: at zero wave number there is still frequency, kind of like an EM waves in a waveguide, where there is a non-zero cut-off frequency at which the wavelength goes to infinity (i.e., a non propagating excitation). Mass is not matter, matter is more aligned with conserved quantum numbers...stuff that can't be destroyed w/o antimatter.

Comment: The question was "why". All of these answers are describing "what" and "when" but not "why". You have math which models what's happening and lets you predict what will happen but that's it. If you had more than that we'd be able to extract E=mc^2 energy from matter on a whim, and vice versa, like on Star Trek. I don't get why people think having mathematical equations that describe something means you actually understand why and how it's happening.

Comment: @PeterMoore you missed the part about conserving quantum numbers. You can't just make charge or lepton number go away. Why is charge conserved? Local U(1) gauge invariance. (See: Noether's Theorem).

Comment: I know about conservation of charge. It doesn't explain why you wind up with massless photons and nearly massless neutrinos rather than a massive boson-like blob. The closest I've seen to an answer here is "nature prefers lower rest mass" but even that sounds like just a postulate that seems to fit what we observe.

Comment: You can make a massive boson like blob, the $Z^0$, but you have to collide a positron beam with and electron beam at $M_Zc^2$, which is large. This is not what ppl usually call "annihilation", rather it is $s$-channel scattering.

Comment: You *still* haven't addressed my first comment. Why does electron + positron annihilation release energy? Why don't they just totally annihilate, leaving nothing?

Comment: Again, no one has answered this because no one can answer this. The electron and positron get less than a planck length apart due to opposite charge and spin and there is nothing preventing them from getting infinitely close. We have no accepted theory that explains what happens below this scale. Without such a theory we cannot say why the particles transform into other things. We only know that they do. I find it baffling no one wants to fess up to this.

Comment: @PeterMoore Are you equally offended by Compton scattering? The QED amplitude for Compton scattering is related to that of pair production by swapping Mandelstam variable $s$ and $t$. There is also a $u$-channel symmetry. There is an amplitude, therefor it happens. It has nothing to do with the Planck length. You can't even localize and electron to less than a Compton wavelength w/o inputing enough energy to create an electron/positron pair. Regarding opposite spins: no. See ortho- and para-positronium.

Comment: Unless you're telling me that the electrons and photons stop being electrons and photons then Compton scattering has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: this is the last time I answer a why question. The silly comments and down votes aren't worth the effort.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote (& delete my comments) if you answer *"why the collision of these two particles results in the release of energy"*

Comment: @PM2Ring b/c photons have energy.

Comment: So what? The OP is asking why electron + positron annihilation releases energy. Why don't they just cancel each other out totally, leaving nothing? Your answer *needs* to explain that.

Comment: Currently, your answer addresses conservation of charge and of lepton number, but it says nothing about conservation of energy (you could at least mention that antiparticles have positive energy, since it's a common misconception that they have negative energy). It would also be nice if you said something about conservation of momentum, especially angular momentum.